# how to insert a logo image to word by VB6?

Tags: vba, vb6

i work on VB6 project as the following steps:
- open file from dir by clicking a command button . or create a new one.(word document .DOC)
-adding an image JPEG as a logo...
- saving the result
please, anyone can help to design and codding ?

Answer (score 2):

Record the steps in Word's VBA. VBA is the language of VB6.

This is what you get

```
Sub Macro10()
'
' Macro10 Macro
' Macro recorded 7/12/2014 by Fred
'
        Documents.Open FileName:="Doc1.DOC", ConfirmConversions:=True, ReadOnly:= _
                False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:= _
                "", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", _
                Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, DocumentDirection:=wdLeftToRight
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Pictures\"
        Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
                "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Pictures\!cid_image001.gif", LinkToFile:= _
                False, SaveWithDocument:=True
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="Doc1.DOC", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument, _
                LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword _
                :="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
                SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:= _
                False
End Sub
```

So in VB6 create a reference to the document

```
Set Wrd = GetObject("Yourfile")
```

Then adapt the VBA code to your object eg; `wrd.documents.open ...`